# Is there any easy way to duplicate the search functionality of the Google Maps app on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mapkit

I'd like to be able to search and have the results pop up as annotations just like the Maps app on the iPhone. How do I go about doing it, and how difficult is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a forward geocoder to take a string (from your search bar) and find a list of possible matches, with coordinates and such. ... there isn't one included with the MapKit (only a reverse geocoder -- from coordinates to address string).  However, there's a few services out that that do this.  I think GeoSimple, CloudMaps, and a few others.  The one linked below is an objective-c package that pulls results from Google Maps SDK.

http://blog.sallarp.com/ipad-iphone-forward-geocoding-api-google/